# How to Have a View Display Specific Items

Tags: web-part, filter, view

I have a column called Compliance that is a Lookup below:

[image]

I also have a list called Request below that contains the column above. I created a view called Asset. I then Edit the Page and add a Query String Filter Web Part that filters the value based on the Compliance Lookup column below:

[image]

What I’m trying to do is, when users click on the Asset view from the Request list, that it would only show items that have corresponding Compliance Process Title

However, even when I have the correct Connection Settings in the Web Part, it is displaying all items, as shown above, instead of only displaying items that have Compliance Process Title.

Answer (score 0):

NVM. Found I can just filter on if the column Compliance is blank.

Please find clarification.

- I went to Edit the View in my list.
- Within the View settings there is a Filter Setting.
- I set the filter to the Compliance column to show items that "is not
  equal to" and left the bottom text box blank.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/61773)

Comment: Please find clarified answer